# Properties of Unitary operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, unitary-matrices

Is it true that for every unitary extension $U' \supset U$

> $\psi \in \{ {\frak Dom}(U)\}^\perp \Longleftrightarrow U'\psi \in \{ U'({\frak Dom} (U))\}^\perp$

?

My question is: how can I be sure that $\{ {\frak Dom}(U)\}^\perp \subset \{{\frak Dom }(U')\}$? And why does $U' \psi$ belong to $\{ U'({\frak Dom} (U))\}^\perp$ and not simply to $\{{\frak Ran }(U')\}$?

Could you prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that ${\frak Dom}(U)^\perp \subset {\frak Dom }(U')$ if we assume that orthogonal complement in ${\frak Dom}(U)^\perp$ is taken relative to the same space on which the extension $U'$ is defined. More precisely, suppose $B$ is a vector space and $U: A\to A$ is a unitary map defined on a subspace $A = {\frak Dom}(U)$ of $B$. Consider an extension $U':B\to B$ of $U$ defined on the whole space $B$. In this case, we have

$${\frak Dom}(U)^\perp = A^\perp \subset B = {\frak Dom}(U')$$

by construction.

Affirmative answer to the second question follows from the fact that the inverse of a unitary map is its Hermitian adjoint. Let $\psi \in {\frak Dom}(U)^\perp$. To prove that $U'\psi \in (U'{\frak Dom}(U))^\perp$ we need to show that $\langle U'\psi, \phi\rangle = 0$ for every $\phi \in U'{\frak Dom}(U)$. However,

$$
\langle U'\psi, \phi\rangle = \langle \psi, U'^{-1}\phi\rangle = 0
$$

where the last equality follows from the facts that $U'^{-1}\phi \in {\frak Dom}(U)$ and $\psi \in {\frak Dom}(U)^\perp$.

Comment: Because we are taking [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) with respect to $B$. Recall that by definition $A^\perp = \{u\in B\,|\,\langle u, v\rangle = 0 \,\text{for all} \,v\in A\}$.

Comment: Note that both concepts: the orthogonal complement and the extension of an operator assume that there is a "background" space relative to which these concepts are defined. Above, I named this larger space $B$. The assumption we need in order for the first question to have affirmative answer and for the second question to have meaning is that the "background" space we use for orthogonal complements and the one we use to extend $U$ coincide.

Comment: Ok, but what if there exists $u \in A^{\perp}$ but $u \in B^c$ (it's the complement set of $B$)? Then $A^{\perp} \notin B$.

Comment: Since we are defining $A^\perp$ as $\{u\in B\, | \, ...\}$ this is not possible. Also, complementary set also requires a "background" set to be defined or assumed. So when you say $B^c$ relative to what other set do you take the complement?